# Enabling Content-Security-Policy on a minimal web app

Tags: http-headers, sha256, content-security-policy

I'm new to CSP and my goal is to enable the simplest possible CSP header.

Based on reading the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash) and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/) I thought my app should work but unfortunately no luck on Chrome Canary v70.

I setup a [minimal repo](https://github.com/onpaws/csp-test) to reproduce. Can you see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was misunderstanding the details a bit. I'll post my solution here in case it helps someone else in the same boat.

My goal is to serve a React SPA with CSP enabled. The app happens to use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com), which uses [JSS](https://material-ui.com/guides/csp/), which injects inline styles - which of course are blocked by default with CSP.

Because it's a static SPA for the frontend and modifying HTTP headers is out of scope of the SPA, I instead generate a nonce on the web server. The nonce gets injected into the CSP HTTP Header and also in the index.html  tag consistent with what JSS [expects](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/docs/csp.md).

The upside is CSP is protecting the SPA, and we don't have to use `unsafe-inline` escape hatch. The downside, but a small one, is that `index.html` is dynamic now and can't be cached. But seeing as the file is already tiny (<1kb) the benefits of CSP seem worth that tradeoff.